# SSIS Project won't execute in SQL Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

SQL 2014. I have deployed an SSIS project into SSISDB, the project consists of three packages. If I schedule a job to execute the three packages in the project, it doesn't pickup the flat file to process. It finishes and thinks nothing is there to process. But, if I manually execute the first package (right click in SSISDB and select Execute) it processes the flat file and moves it (correctly). The SQL Job step Configurations are identical to the package configurations in SSISDB. Windows Application, Security, and System event logs are clean. SQL Logs are clean. The SQL Agent account has full access to the folder (a unc share). Also changed the share to a mapped network drive, but still nothing. The SQL Agent account is also a sysadmin, just for testing purposes. I am guessing this is permissions related but not sure what else there is to check?

[image: OnWarning Message from SSIS execution]

Comment: do you have variables across the packages that differ or are overridden?

Comment: Is the file share on the same machine as Sql Server agent?  Can you do some old fashioned troubleshooting where you have SSIS produce a directory listing of the folder?

Comment: No variables, for this part of the ssis package.

Comment: The file share is not on the same machine as SQL.

Comment: Does the user, which is used to execute the job, have access to the fileshare? I remember facing a similar problem. I solved it by providing access to the file share to the corresponding user.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. It was a fileshare permissions issue. I  gave the SQL Agent account permissions to the folder, but needed sysadmin to give permissions to the fileshare. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments everyone. It was a fileshare permissions issue. I  gave the SQL Agent account permissions to the folder, but needed sysadmin to give permissions to the fileshare. Thanks!